# Houdini command line render undefined variable

Tags: linux, command-line, render, houdini

I'm trying to render a Houdini scene (I downloaded the free "Bar scene" from sideFX website) on linux via command line using the following line of code:

```
 /opt/hfs18.0.499/bin/hrender -d mantra1 /home/ciara/Documents/Houdini_test/BarScene/scene_layout_v01.hip
```

but I receive the following error.

```
HB: Undefined variable
```

I'm wondering what i did wrong and/or if the issue is related to the houdini installation/configuration or it's just my fault.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to load the Houdini UI on that linux machine?

Comment: yes i do, and i can also start the render

Comment: ******************************* UPDATE ************************************
i tried the following:

`$ cd /opt/hfs18.0
$ source houdini_setup
$ export HB='/opt/hfs18.0.499/bin'`

so now the HB error disappeared but apparently there's a python one
(Python Version: 2.7)